# Evaluate $\int (x-6)^{\frac{5}{2}}dx$ using $u$ substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

Section 5.2. Will somebody verify this solution for me? Thanks

Evaluate $\int (x-6)^{\frac{5}{2}}dx$ using $u$ substitution

Let $u=x-6$. Then $\frac{d}{dx} u = \frac{d}{dx}(x-6)=1$.

Thus $\frac{du}{dx}=1$

"Multiplying" both sides of this equation by $dx$ we get:

$du=dx$

Thus $\int (x-6)^{\frac{5}{2}}dx=\int u^{\frac{5}{2}} du = \frac{u^{\frac{7}{2}}}{\frac{7}{2}} + C=\frac{2u^{\frac{7}{2}}}{7}  + C$

Comment: It is correct. Don't forget to make the backwards substitution.

Comment: It is correct, but why do you not reverse the substitution at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct (and revert the substitution in the end!). Please consider using an online-calculator (like [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%28x-6%29%5E%285%2F2%29) or [SymbolLab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/integral-calculator/%5Cint%20%5Cleft(x-6%5Cright)%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B5%7D%7B2%7D%7Ddx)) for verifying your solutions instead of asking multiple question of the same kind within a short preiod of time (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588520/integrate-int-6-5x2-10xdx-using-u-substitution) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588532/evaluate-int-5x4-sqrtx55dx-using-u-substitution)).

Comment: I agree with this, but I think the OP is not interested only in the final answer, but a verification of their methodology as well.

Comment: @an4s SymbolLab offers a step-by-step solution aswell (see the given link).